# Запрет подключения библиотеки

Tags: c#, dll

Работаю над проектом, в нем используется Guardant.SDK.
Написал свою обертку над методами SDK и сделал это в отдельном проекте библиотеки.
Теперь встал вопрос. 
Как запретить подключать данную библиотеку к другим проекта не из решения, или указать список сборок которым разрешено будет подключать эту библиотеку?
Связано это с тем, что данная либа будет распространяться вместе с проектом, следственно кто-нибудь может подрубить к себе её и получить доступ к методам управления защитой Guardant.

Comment: Кратко: никак...

Comment: Могу дать совет, подпишите ваш проект, а в самой библиотеке используйте token key для того ,чтобы определить кому разрешать использовать dll, а кому - нет.